# How to pass argument using getx?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

```
Get.rootDelegate.toNamed('/note', arguments: 'test_data');

Get.arguments <= It makes null.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: To the seconde page make:final title = Get.arguments as String;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you migh be missing something. While you're setting this parameters using the rootDelegate

```
onPressed: () => Get.rootDelegate.toNamed(Routes.RECEIVER, arguments: true, parameters: {'bool': 'true'}),
```

You try to retrieve them from the Get context:

```
Get.arguments
```

You should be using:

```
Get.rootDelegate.parameters
```

`Get.rootDelegate.parameters` will work

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question but rather gives a workaround. This ay work for very simple arguments (like bool or String) being passed but DOES NOT WORK if you wish to pass complex arguments such as Objects or Custom Classes.

Answer (score 2):

Send arguments

```
  Map<String, dynamic> parameter = {
      'name': "pradeep",
      'object': SomeObject,
     
    };

Get.rootDelegate.toNamed(Routes.nextpage, arguments: parameter );
```

Recieve arguments

```
var someObject= Get.rootDelegate.arguments()['object'];
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `rootDelegate` in **GetX**, you. no longer get the arguments via `Get.arguments` but rather using `Get.rootDelegate.arguments()` (note arguments is a function).

In your case the correct way is as follows:

```
Get.rootDelegate.toNamed('/note', arguments: 'test_data');

Get.rootDelegate.arguments() // Result: 'test_data'
```